# Wrong values on x-axis on linechart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart in my android application but the x-axis is wrong formatted and label are duplicated. Here my code

```
private fun lineChart(exams: List<Exam>) {
        val formatter: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")

        val lineChart: LineChart = linechart
        lineChart.animateY(1000)
        val d = Description()
        d.text = "TEST"
        lineChart.description = d

        val yValues: ArrayList<Entry> = ArrayList()
        var count = 0
        for (exam in exams.sortedByDescending { exam -> exam.date }) {
            if (getString(R.string.scores_array_admitted) != exam.score)
                yValues.add(Entry(count++.toFloat(), exam.score.toFloat()))
        }

        val lineDataSet = LineDataSet(yValues, getString(R.string.linechart_score_label))
        val dataSet: ArrayList<ILineDataSet> = ArrayList()
        dataSet.add(lineDataSet)

        val lineData = LineData(dataSet)

        val xAxis: XAxis = lineChart.xAxis

        val values = ArrayList<String>()
        for (exam in exams.sortedByDescending { exam -> exam.date }) {
            if (getString(R.string.scores_array_admitted) != exam.score)
                values.add(formatter.format(exam.date))
        }

        val array = arrayOfNulls<String>(values.size)
        values.toArray(array)

        var aa = array!!


        xAxis.valueFormatter = MyAxisValueFormatter(aa)

        lineChart.data = lineData

    }
```

In debug I see that the value in the arrays are correct, 2 exams and in **values** array the label are the two date of the exam and they are exactly two, but when I run my application the result is this[image]

In x axis I would have only two date

Comment: ["Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Since the dates on the x axis seem to be the problem, it would be especially helpful to see the code of MyAxisValueFormatter

Comment: Here the code for MyAxisValueFormatter https://pastebin.com/fjfbWr9w